# Changing Date format in xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, date, xamarin

Currently datepicker is seting date to textview in m/d/yyyy Format.but i want to change a dateformat from m/d/yyyy to dd-mm-yyyy. I googled about this topic.but didnt find solution.Any help is appreciated.

Main.axml

```
  <TextView
        android:layout_weight="80"
        android:id="@+id/dateDisplay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select Date" />
    <Button
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:id="@+id/pickDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pick date" />
```

mainactivity.cs

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Create your application here
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

             dateDisplay = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.dateDisplay);
             pickDate = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.pickDate);

            // add a click event handler to the button
            pickDate.Click += delegate { ShowDatePickerDialog (); };

            // get the current date
            //date = DateTime.Today;

            // display the current date (this method is below)
           // UpdateDisplay (date);
        }

        void ShowDatePickerDialog()
        {
            var dialog = new DatePickerFragment(this, DateTime.Now, this);
            dialog.Show(FragmentManager, null);
        }

        public void OnDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
        {
            var newDate = new DateTime(year, monthOfYear + 1, dayOfMonth);
            UpdateDisplay(newDate);
        }

        void UpdateDisplay(DateTime selectedDate)
        {
           // selectedDate.GetDateTimeFormats('d');
          //  dateDisplay.Text = selectedDate.GetDateTimeFormats('d').ToString();

             dateDisplay.Text = selectedDate.ToString("d");
        }
    }
```

DatePickerFragment.cs

```
 public class DatePickerFragment : DialogFragment
    {
        private readonly Context context;
        private DateTime date;
        private readonly DatePickerDialog.IOnDateSetListener listener;

        public DatePickerFragment(Context context, DateTime date, DatePickerDialog.IOnDateSetListener listener)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.date = date;
            this.listener = listener;
        }

        public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedState)
        {
            var dialog = new DatePickerDialog(context, listener, date.Year, date.Month - 1, date.Day);
            return dialog;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you display your `dd-MM-yyyy` formatted `DateTime`? Is it here: `dialog.Show(FragmentManager, null);`? What is the data type of `FragmentManager`? The format is just the representation. The `DateTime` struct itself has no format.

Comment: @Ian i am setting or displaying it in textview.I want to represent date in 31-04-2015(date-month-year)

Comment: OK, could you show that part of the code? How you display in textview, as well as the data type which you pass to the view, I mean...

Comment: @Ian In mainactivity.cs i am calling DatePickerFragment class and onDateset function i am getting year,month,and date values and these value is displayed  to textview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this in `UpdateDisplay`:

```
dateDisplay.Text = selectedDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Comment: it says error showing "cannot convert from string to system.IformatProvider"

Comment: Odd. Just used this in a Xamarin.Android activity, `var test = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");`, compiled fine and `test` shows to be a string.